# gtk-3 accessibility warning

Tags: xubuntu, gtk3

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 with the most recent libgtk-3-dev library. Then I recompiled all my C programs. Now all these programs output a warning which was not there before, when I had these programs running under Xubuntu 13.1 with the old libgtk-3-dev. The warning is

```
** (program.x:2430): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-DpOEDwyIbh: Connection refused
```

How can one suppress this message?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this happens only if Xubuntu is freshly installed.

In Settings Manager one can enable accessibility, reboot, disable accessibilty, and reboot. Then this warning is permanently gone. It seems to be a miracle designed to bewilder innocent C programmers when they install Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem.
   It is fresh installed Xubuntu (ubuntu with xfce).
   And camera (webcam of DELL Latitude E6430) did not work anywhere: not in 'cheese', not in 'guvc' ('guvcview'), not in 'Google Hangout', not in '', not in '',

As i guessed, libgtk-3-dev was absent...
   This helped:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

After this 'cheese' started to work. 
   But 'guvcview' still gives error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```